# Is there any situation the REST service's http response code is 200, but the method returns false

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

most of the deleteObject methods will return a boolean value to indicate whether this operation succeed or not.

But from what I can see, if something wrong happened, http response code will not be 200, if http response code is 200, then the method returns true.

So I want to know in what situation http response code is not 200 and method return false, so that I can check this condition and display proper messages instead of just telling deletion failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods like **deleteObject** only return true or an exception when something is wrong or  if it does not success. In other words, there is no any situation to return false